# It shows incompatible datatype while I assign values to array

Tags: java, android

I am having the incompatible datatype error. What can I do to remove it. I am getting error at [getsubject] on the last line where the value is asigned to tt1. It shows that getsubject is of incompatible type.

```
//FOR TIMETABLE 1
String[][] tt1=new String[10][10];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_entry);
final EditText subject=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.subject);
final EditText professor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.professor);
add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //Adding and Displaying subjects
            String getsubject=subject.getText().toString();
            String getprofessor=professor.getText().toString();
           tt1[getsubject][getprofessor]=scan.next();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `int` value to access an array item but you use `String`.

Comment: I tried putting and index and the error got eliminated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HumeraShaikh Happy to help)

Answer (score 0):

In **JAVA** always array store data at specific index **For example,**

```
int[] temp = new int[10];
temp[0] = 1;
temp[1] = 2 ......
```

For here you are assigning `String` as an index which gives  **Incompatible types** error, so make sure assign `int` value to the array index.

For more information visit 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Glad to help you! Happy Coding :)